# Representing a User Entered String Diagonally

Tags: c++

I am currently a bit stuck. I need to write a program in c++ that allows a user to enter a string (any length with any amount of spaces) and the program then need's to represent this diagonally. I can get it to work but only for the first word and not for any word's entered after the first word. Below you can find my code.

Thanks People!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string strHello;
    cin >> strHello;

    for(int k = 0; k < strHello.length(); k++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= k; x++)
        {
            if (k==x)
                cout << strHello.at(x);
            else
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need the program to be written in c++? in c it's a very easy task just `for (i = 0 ; str[i] != '\0' ; ++i) printf("%*s%c\n", 1 + i, " ", str[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

Yes the problem is as others have mentioned, that `>>` operator stops reading at the first white space character found, so `std::getline()` does the job, and aditionally you don't need the nested loops, take a look at this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int
main(void)
{
    string text;
    string spaces;

    getline(cin, text);

    for (int k = 0 ; k < text.length() ; ++k)
        cout << (spaces += ' ') << text.at(k) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your input, not your output.  The problem is that you only call

```
cin >> strHello;
```

once.  This reads in only the first sequence of non-white-space characters that are delimited by any amount of {white-space, begin of input, end of input}.  So, your program will only read in the first such sequence of any input and discards any white space in the input.

Answer (score 1):

`cin >>` will break up the input string at whitespace characters. You should use `getline()` instead.

```
getline(cin,strHello);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getline, e.g

```
std::getline(cin, strHello);
```

`cin` will read only the first string it see before white space. e.g. "hello world" will have only hello in strHello.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program that I think will help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define MAX_LEN 100
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char strHello[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };
    cout << "Enter a string";
    cin.getline(strHello, MAX_LEN);
    for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(strHello); k++){
        for (int x = 0; x <= k; x++){
            if (k == x)
                cout << strHello[x];
            else
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```